# Combobox.Items não sendo atualizado

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

Estou criando um (vários) combobox em **runtime** e tentando setar manualmente um `SelectedValue` 'padrão', porém percebi que mesmo setando manualmente um valor que existe dentro do combo nada é selecionado.

Eu já conferi se o tipo de dados bate (ambos são `long`).

Abaixo o código em que eu crio o combo:

```
ComboBox cmb = new ComboBox()
{
    DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown,
    BackColor = Color.FromArgb(210, 211, 213),
    ForeColor = Color.Black,
    Location = new Point(5, y),
    Size = new Size(265, 10),
    Font = new Font("Verdana", 11f, FontStyle.Regular),
    FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Popup,
    AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend,
    AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems,
    Tag = null
};

cmb.DataSource = null;
cmb.ValueMember = "Id";
cmb.DisplayMember = "Login";
cmb.DataSource = UsuarioDB.FindAll().Where(x => x.Id > 0).OrderBy(x => x.Login).ToList();
cmb.SelectedValue = (long)1; //Aqui estou setando manualmente o valor para testar
```

Há três coisas importantes a pontuar:

1. Debugando o código eu vejo que a propriedade `DataSource` está correta com todos os registros, porém a propriedade `Items` está vazia;
2. Mesmo com a propriedade `Items` vazia, o combo mostra os valores exatamente como eu preciso (digo, em execução) e ao trocar o valor selecionado e tentar capturar pelo `SelectedValue` o valor vem certo.
3. No mesmo form é criado um combobox (este em **design time**), onde eu também seto o `SelectedValue` manualmente, porém neste funciona certinho.

Alguma ideia do que pode ser?

Comment: Ao invés de `SelectedValue` pq não usa `SelectedIndex`?

Comment: Porque eu preciso selecionar com base no `ValueMember` que é o **Id**.

Comment: Só pra constar então, você quer selecionar um item no combo baseado no seu valor que é um `long` resultante do `DataSource`, correto?

Comment: Correto @FelipeDouradinho

Comment: Eu particularmente utilizo desta forma, quando associo um `DataSource` ao ComboBox: `cmb.SelectedIndex = cmb.Items.IndexOf(UsuarioDB.Where(x => x.Id == 1).FirstOrDefault());`

Comment: Nah, o problema não tem a ver com isso. Aliás, você faz uma consulta no banco só pra validar isso? Parece ser desnecessário.

Answer (score 0):

Tente assim:

```
cmb.SelectedIndex = 1;
```

Ou se quiser preencher a partir de um valor:

```
int index = cmb.FindString("valor");
cmb.SelectedIndex = index;
```